# Two methods running at the same time

Tags: java

I basically have a mobile phone made in the app called BlueJ. It enters a duration of the phone call and you insert credit. Every minute is equal to a pound. So basically if I insert 5 pounds and 6 minutes, it will do 6-5.

In this case, it isn't working.

The credit is successful, but as the credit changes, the duration minuses from the NEW credit, and not the one that was entered.

Is there a way around this or a way to run it at the same time, or for the old values before they change?

The issue is where it says:

```
    credit = credit - duration;
    duration = duration - credit;
```

Many thanks.

```
   public void makePhoneCall()
    {
        if(credit == 0)
        System.out.println("Insert more than 0 credit to make a phone call!");
    else {
        if(credit >= duration) {
        System.out.println("The phone number " + number + " is being dialed for    " + duration + " minutes");
        credit = credit - duration;
        duration = duration - credit;
    }
    else {
        if(credit < duration)
        System.out.println("You do not have enough credit to make a phone call! Your credit is " + credit + " pounds");
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i got what you are trying to do, but here's what i understood:

With `credit = credit - duration;` you are redefining the value of "credit". But you want to subtract the original value of "credit" in the line below.

You could simply store the value before modifying it in another variable like so:

```
int oldCredit = credit;
credit = oldCredit - duration;
duration = duration - oldCredit;
```